# How do I update a subnode from a master node based on a property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am working on a system that is tracking parts usage by a "type" ( Inside or Outside in my example). When the nodes are loaded, they don't have a type so they come in as "unknown". They are linked to the master nodes but the chain could be 6 or 7 layers down. I really won't know how many at this point. So my simplified graph looks like this.

[image]

The master nodes (Final and Final2) dictate what the class of the subnodes of Type:Part are, regardless of the level. There are other nodes but they don't have a Type:Part so they are unaffected. Final nodes are unconnected so I will have one or the other but never both.

After processing, they should look like this

[image]

I actually have to update the attribute on the subnodes, I can't just have it as a query. How do I make that work in Neo4j ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have the type:'Part' in the image before the preprocessing is done, so I will use that to find nodes that need updating. After you have imported the data, you can run the following query to update the missing types

```
// get all nodes with "unknown"/"Part" type
MATCH (n:Node{Type:"Part"})
// get the master node
MATCH (n)-[:RELATIONSHIP*..10]->(master)
WHERE NOT (master)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->()
// Set the missing type
SET n.Type = master.Class
```

This is based on the image you provided, maybe you had some different property names in mind and maybe your relationship has some other types as well.

Comment: That does it. Yes, lots of different property names and relationships but this gets us close enough. Thank you